# Science Fair Poster Document Class

Tags: documentclass

I am creating a trifold poster for a science fair (ISEF). Most posters I have seen on the internet look similar - they probably use the same document class. The key characteristic that I am interested in is block sections. Can someone point me to this document class or a template?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Have you checked https://ctan.org/topic/poster ?

Comment: There (probably) is no specific poster template. You can use `article` and do a perfectly fine job. -> https://github.com/johannesbottcher/LatexPosterExperiments/blob/master/posterTest.png